# Jquery float point not working

Tags: jquery

In text-field float point not working after using query function.Here I have used a function for digits.That means user can type only digits.

```
 $(".number-field").keypress(function(e)
    {
    var code = e.which || e.keyCode;

    if((code >= 48 && code <= 57) || code == 8){
    console.debug(code);
    }
    else {
    return false;
    }
    });
```

Here float point not working.How can I solve it?

Comment: It would be great if you can elaborate your question.

Comment: Be precise with your question so that u can get correct answers soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
 $(".number-field").keypress(function(e)
        {
            var code = e.which || e.keyCode;

               if((code >= 48 && code <= 57) || code == 8 || code == 46|| code==110){
                 console.debug(code);
               } 
               else {
                 return false;
               }
        });
```

here 110 for decimal point .For details.see this link www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: In this code he have used Javascript char codes.Here 48 means 0 and 57 means 9.That means when user will type in field,user can't type any character or float number.User have to type a number from 0-9.Here for float point need an additional Char code that is 110.
for details please see this link  www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: Might I suggest replacing these "magic numbers" by defining constants up front? `var CHAR_0 = "0".charCodeAt(0)` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a task for jQuery, or even JavaScript. You can use [HTML5's `step` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-step):

```
<input type="number" step="0.001" />
```

Adjust to how many decimal places you want to allow - the above allows up to thousandths to be specified.

Alternatively, to allow arbitrary-length numbers with optional thousand-separators, try this:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[+-]?(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*|\d*)(\.\d+)?" />
```

However keep in mind that this solution is not locale-aware, so for example in places where `,` is the decimal separator, this input will not work as the user might expect. Same for places where `'` is the thousand separator.

Note that in general you should NEVER restrict user input. Let them type whatever they want, then attempt to validate it afterwards.

Comment: +1 for *"Note that in general..."* And for `step`, maybe in 2017 or 2018 it'll be well-enough supported to actually use it. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's supported in all browsers. It's only people who actively make our lives difficult by disabling Windows Update that it won't work for ;)

Comment: @ Niet: When version of IE started supporting it? (And don't discount the people stuck on Windows XP who can't get past IE8.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That would be IE10. So that does mean people stuck on XP are left out... But XP is unsupported now anyway, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @ Niet: Thanks. Re Windows XP: Nope, that's a common myth. Volume license clients (big companies, governments) receive Windows XP support for the entire lifetime of Windows 7. One hopes they'll be a bit more proactive than they were with IE6, but... It's funny, though, isn't it, how all other browser vendors are perfectly capable of making their up-to-date products work with Windows XP, but Microsoft isn't...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah, fair enough. Still, it will at least let you input stuff. Validation should always be server-side anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're explicitly disallowing all keypresses except for digits and the backspace, which means you're explicitly disallowing `.` (or `,` depending on your culture). So don't do that. `.` is code 46. `,` is code 44. You should be able to modify the `if` to allow the relevant one. If you want to allow negative numbers, you might consider allowing `-`. (Easy way to find out the code for most printable characters: Put this in the console: `"-".charCodeAt(0)`.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(".number-field2").keypress(function(e){
   var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
   if((code >= 48 && code <= 57) || code == 8
               || code == 46){ // for .
       console.debug(code);
   } 
   else {
       return false;
   }
});
```